# How can I search for JS variables with VBScript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, vbscript

How do you search the InternetExplorer.Application model for JavaScript variables?

A friend of mine is trying to retrieve the value of a JS variable within IE in order to automate some tests.  He has code that can do this already:

```
dim ie
set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.navigate2 "myUrl.com"
ie.visible = True
myVal = ie.document.script.s.myVar
```

What he'd like to do is provide a list of several variables ("myVar" in this case), search the object model by variable name to get a reference to it, and then use that reference to obtain the value.  What he (and I for that matter) don't know is how to obtain a reference to the variable given only it's name.

Any ideas?